# Convert curl to $.ajax to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded data

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

I am trying to convert the following `curl` code to $.ajax.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://trackcmp.net/event \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'actid={{actid}}&key={{key}}&event={{event}}&eventdata={{eventdata}}&visit=%7B%22email%22%3A%22{{email}}%22%7D'
```

This (with the appropriate values) returns a 200 and json saying the event call was a success.

My ajax is here:

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  url: "https://trackcmp.net/event",
  async: "true",
  data: "actid={{act_id}}&key={{my_key}}&event={{eventName}}&eventdata=${{eventdata}}&visit=%7B%22email%22%3A%22${userEmail}%22%7D",
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('success:', data)
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  }
});
```

}

This returns a 200 but no JSON (and is not working properly on trackcpm.net. I can include more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Data takes a javascript key, value pair object instead of a query string

```
data:{
 actid: act_id,
 key: my_key,
 event: eventName,
 eventData: eventData,
 visit: "%7B%22email%22%3A%22${userEmail}%22%7D"
}
```

You will need to fill in the variables accordingly.

Comment: I used a string because of this from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/: data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).